# How to use retrofit to connect to my local REST API in Realt device

Tags: android, retrofit

Hey there i m trying to do some http call to the localhost server using retrofit in android
i've tried my local ip but it didn't work tho
i get this error:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.52 (port 3000) after 10000ms
```

retrofit initialization

```
 private val retrofit by lazy {
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.52:3000/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }
```

my API call

```
interface ItemApi {

    @GET("items/{id}")
    suspend fun getItems(@Path("id")id:Int): Item
}
```

not sure how to do it in the real device , many article said to use the local ip , i did but the error in the top occurred

Comment: I think it would be easier to test it on a emulator, where is your webservice deployed? If it's locally deployed on your pc it's hard to say if it's accessibile from an external device, even if you're connected to same LAN (probably you have a firewall on your machine)

Answer (score 1):

On an emulator, you can use `10.0.2.2` to access your local machine:

```
private val retrofit by lazy {
    Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2:3000/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
}
```

It would be really easier than using a physical external device, since you don't have to deal with your network firewall